# C3js timeseries can't show continuous line

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, c3.js, timeserieschart

I want to use c3 to show device information with timeseries.
Here is my json data.

```
  json: [
            {datetime: '2016-01-02 12:00:01.001', wifi: 1},
            {datetime: '2016-01-02 12:00:01.999', wifi: 0},
            {datetime: '2016-01-02 12:00:03.000', GPS: 0},
            {datetime: '2016-01-02 12:00:04.003', wifi: 1},
            {datetime: '2016-01-02 12:00:05.959', GPS: 1},
            {datetime: '2016-01-02 12:00:06.006', wifi: 0},
        ],
```

I find it can't show continuous line for each wifi / gps.
Is it a bug or any method can show continuous line?

[The line what I expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3Cw0.png)

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        xFormat: '%Y-%M-%d %H:%M:%S.%L',
        json: [
            {datetime: '2016-01-02 12:00:01.001', wifi: 1},
            {datetime: '2016-01-02 12:00:01.999', wifi: 0},
            {datetime: '2016-01-02 12:00:03.000', GPS: 0},
            {datetime: '2016-01-02 12:00:04.003', wifi: 1},
            {datetime: '2016-01-02 12:00:05.959', GPS: 1},
            {datetime: '2016-01-02 12:00:06.006', wifi: 0},
        ],
        keys: {
            x: 'datetime',
            value: ['wifi','GPS'],
        },
        types: {
            wifi: 'line',
            GPS:'line',
        },
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'timeseries',
                tick: {
                    format: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
            }
        },
    },
    zoom: {
        enabled: true
    },
});
```

[Source Code](https://jsfiddle.net/7xs3d50h/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that it's an old issue and the solution is "connectNull: true".

```
    var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        xFormat: '%Y-%M-%d %H:%M:%S.%L',
        json: [
            {datetime: '2016-01-02 12:00:01.001', wifi: 1},
            {datetime: '2016-01-02 12:00:01.999', wifi: 0},
            {datetime: '2016-01-02 12:00:04.003', wifi: 1},
            {datetime: '2016-01-02 12:00:06.006', wifi: 0},
            {datetime: '2016-01-02 12:00:03.000', GPS: 0},
            {datetime: '2016-01-02 12:00:05.959', GPS: 1},
        ],
        keys: {
            x: 'datetime',
            value: ['wifi','GPS'],
        },
        types: {
            wifi: 'step',
            GPS:'step',
        },
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'timeseries',
                tick: {
                    format: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
            }
        },
    },
    zoom: {
        enabled: true
    },
line: {
    connectNull: true
}
});
```

[SourceCode](https://jsfiddle.net/655pcqg1/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I never used c3, but this is my guess: you have to specify the values for `wifi`and `GPS` for all your datetimes.

I just added 0 where there was no value. Look what happened, now you have a line chart: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/oshujxux/

Comment: Thank you, the we can't add all value for all timestamp. There will be performance issue on browser. I just find the solution: https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/563